# Is it possible to set the default view on SE websites to be the "Newest" tab?

Tags: feature-request, tabs, newest-questions

Is it possible to set the default view on SE websites to be the "Newest" tab?

Whenever I enter the site from my favorites, I must navigate from the homepage to a question; both at the normal site and at the finish line. It shows me things that don't interest me from the community bot:

[image: Homepage]

but what actually interests me is this tab:

[image: Newest questions]

**It seems to me that something like a pinned tab is needed.**

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change your favorite to point at that page instead of the homepage?

Comment: Not really, I can do it, of course, but if I'm on the main site and I go to the meta site through the menu (without using the favorite) ... it falls into Home.

Comment: I have to say that I agree with this. Since I joined 7 years ago, it's been a constant irritant having to make that extra click or set of clicks from a review queue to get back to my preferred view. It seems not un-doable to be able to set personal preferences to go to the view of choice by default. I'd class this under - workflow. It also increases the data used for mobile/tablet when not on a local Wi-Fi network - cost implications.

Comment: This is especially annoying on mobile, as you need two clicks to get back to newest. I think it would be best to combine both of these pages into one page. (Having two pages like this is confusing, even for some of the most experienced users on the network. Nobody knows the difference between the active tab on each page.)

Comment: I mean, as long as it doesn't take the default away from those of us who prefer the current personally tailored home page.

Comment: that's why I said it was an option for users ... in my case I like the view of the tab question / most recent ... and if it is a bit irritating I have 4 years in this, but now that I am more active having that giving those clicks is hitting the data plan ... XD

Comment: I don't disagree, but lately options have been being removed, not added... hence why I felt the need to make that point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is something that annoys me as long as I've been an active member of SE. But at the same time I wouldn't suggest something as drastic as getting rid of the "Home" page all together.

I think the Home page does have some merit, especially for the new and casual users. It explicitly filters out garbage (post with extremely negative scores), and displays questions based on your tag preferences.

At the same time more experienced users have little need for those features. Users that care to moderate their sites do want to see the bad posts and take care of them by either bringing them up to standard or by closing/deleting them. Subject matter experts at the same time mostly use tag filters to look for questions they can answer, so they also have very little need for the Home page.

Now what I would find interesting to know is how many people actively visit a question from either the Home page or the Questions page, and if and how that correlates with a users reputation or their overall time actively spend on the site. My hypotheses would be that the more experienced users make most use of the Questions page, while newer or casual users use the Home page.

So in conclusion I would love to see a setting that sets the Question page as the default view. This can either be a profile setting, or to be more discoverable a togglebox on the Questions page.